# MySQL update Trigger to update data table value After Insert on another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update, triggers

I have been stumbling on writing some an MySQL trigger and was hopping someone could help me find the most elegant solution to solve my issue. I have Looked many places and cannot seem to find where the bug is in this code. I also tried not adjusting the delimiter as it seems to create problems I am able to create a trigger without setting the delimiter if I replace the update statement by something else.

The code I have is:

```
USE MyTable
DELIMITER //

--Trigger to update Scheduling 'Status' and 'Retries' values
CREATE TRIGGER `Scheduling-Updatde_After_Result-Insert`
      AFTER INSERT ON Results
      FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
               UPDATE `Scheduling`
                      SET
                               Running = FALSE,
                               Retries = Retries + 1
                       WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
      END//

DELIMITER ;
```

I get the following errors:

**18:03:25  [DELIMITER - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]**  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER

CREATE TRIGGER `acapella`.`Scheduling-Updatde_After_Result-Insert`
 ' at line 1

*Code: 1064 SQL State: 42000* --- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER

CREATE TRIGGER `Scheduling-Updatde_After_Result-Insert`
 ' at line 1

**18:03:25  [END - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1064, SQL State: 42000]** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END
DELIMITER' at line 1

*Code: 1064 SQL State: 42000* --- You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END
DELIMITER' at line 1

Comment: my be need a semicolon after end `END;//`

Comment: Actually  i already tried this syntax